# How to Run a java app running in localhost with AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have created an (AWS) Amazon web service server to run some Application created in Java, this app takes some port for example 8888 and runs locally in localhost:8888/index.html.

I can check that localhost:8888/index.html is working perfectly with the command:

```
curl localhost:8888/index.html
```

The thing is I don't know how to access to this app from my domain name, I know there is a way to do this using **nginx**, but unfortunately, all tutorials are about Node.js.

Following this [article](https://medium.com/@utkarsh_verma/configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-application-on-aws-ubuntu-16-04-server-872922e21d38) I managed to run a Node.JS app (simple app that prints hello world) running on localhost:8080, and when I access my domain name I could get the Hello world message printed!, my question is, can I do the same with a Java Application?

Comment: Have you considered [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html)? It takes care of a lot of the details for you.

Comment: I have read about it, but unfortunately, my AWS is EC2.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk starts a fully configured EC2 instance for you. Either way, your problem is you're listening on `127.0.0.1` but you need something to listen on `0.0.0.0`. It can be a proper nginx proxy (that Elastic Beanstalk will seamlessly help you setup) or you can just have your Java server listen on `0.0.0.0` (not recommended but OK for testing).

Answer (score 2):

One best bet is to get the host ip and use it; instead of using localhost which sometimes mapped to 127.0.0.1, in such situation you can connect to the app within the host but not from outside.

Can you share the VM details?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!, I have a server EC2 with ubuntu 14.04 operating system, and two IPs one private `IPPRIV` that I get when I run `ifconfig` on a terminal and one public `IPPUB`, the public IP is the domain name IP and I can access through the browser using it, and ssh with it. 
PD: Due to confidentiality I can't share the real IPs, really sorry.